# Importing an App to Fiori Launchpad - Error

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

So I'm having this problem with the [My Leave Requests App (V.2) for SAP Business Suite](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F1311')/W13). I'm trying to import it to 'my' Fiori Launchpad (image 1) but I'm having this error and I cannot solve it. I've searched about it but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

**App on Fiori Launchpad:**

[image: App on Fiori Launchpad]

**The ERROR:**

[image: Error]

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try /IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP for the gateway and /IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP for the gateway and the backend.

Try /UI2/CHIP_SYNCHRONIZE_CACHE. Afterwards run /UI2/CHIP_CHDR and check it for errors.

Try /UI2/DELETE_CACHE_AFTER_IMP. Afterwards run /UI2/DELETE_CACHE.

Try /UI5/UPDATE_CACHEBUSTER. Afterwards run /UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES.

And did you activate the services? Run SICF and check if /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/hcm_lrq_cre is activated. Same for BSP. Run SICF and check if sap/bc/bsp/hcm_lrq_cre is activated.

Comment: HTTP status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access to the requested resource by the client which usually means you don't have permission to access the resource.

Is your component.js readable on file system level?
Any typos in the path?

Please see: [Internal error](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3699213); 
[Component.js](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3842082); 
[Error](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3728819); 
[Error in neg. cache](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3822740)

Comment: @n01dea The first two worked out (/IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP and  /IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP) the other 3 don't work on SAP. The services and the app are both activated.

Comment: User n01dea mentions both transactions and reportnames/tablename.
/IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP and /IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP are transactions.
The other ones are reportnames and a tablename. 
You might call the reports with transaction SE38 and providing the reportname.
Table can be checked with transaction SE16.
This [link](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3822740) might be helpful:

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I didn't have time to answer. We've tried this right now, again, and it didn't work :/

Comment: We've executed all the steps of @n01dea but on the table 'UI2/CHIP_CHDR' we are full of errors. What should I do?

Comment: please post those errors. give the user with which you access the launchpad in transaction PFCG the SAP_ALL authorization. if it's now working it's an authorization error. trace the error in transaction ST01. give missing authorization(s).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is due to the corresponding node is not active in Tcode SICF.
You get 403 error in such a case.